# Autodesk Forge - Highlight parent geometry seperate from leaf geometry

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Using Autodesk Forge `v7.2.1`, we have a situation where a `.rvt` BIM model has geometry (`fragId`) that is associated with a group element, which also has leaf elements that have their own geometry.

**Is there anyway to separate the highlighting of child elements when a parent is selected?**

Or is this due to an abnormal `.rvt` model?

What happens is when the "cap" that is associated with the group is selected, all the leaf elements are also highlighted. So when you `cmd/ctrl + click` to select/deselect the leaf children, it appears in the viewer that the selection isn't working, as the leaf elements are always highlighted.

Some visuals to help:

- [Here's a gif showing leaf elements being selected while also being highlighted from the parent selection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmIFB.gif)
- [Here's a gif showing leaf elements being selected/deselected, and then the same when the parent is selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgbw3.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same behavior with regular models (where fragments are only attached to leaf nodes), so it's not related to your specific Revit model:

[image]

(gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hixqV.jpg)

If I remember correctly, this was done for performance reasons, but I agree that the disconnect between "what's selected in the model browser" and "what's selected in the scene" is a bit confusing.

I'll pass your comment to the engineering team.

Comment: Thank you. We're also allowing the Model Panel to `selectonly` when single clicking a node. So many times a parent is selected and it becomes confusing that the leaf's aren't technically in the selection, but they are highlighted in the viewer as if they were.